Disable Picom shadow for iDesk
I’m using AwesomeWM with Picom, and recently I started using iDesk. The shadow provided by Picom is spoiled on iDesk icons though:

So I wanna disable it.
How can I disable shadows for iDesk?

Update: xprop is returning this for iDesk:
_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DESKTOP
_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_STATE_BELOW, _NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN, _NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_PAGER, _NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_TASKBAR, _NET_WM_STATE_STICKY

